# Best Design Pattern for Black-Box Trading

Tags: design-patterns, trading, black-box

I am starting a project that involves coding a Black-Box Trading Bot for a strategy one of my friends created, and I was trying to think of what the best design pattern would be.
My current thought is that I should use the Actor model to allow for lots of concurrent calculation and information passing.

Anyone else have any ideas? Or agree?

Comment: You might get some ideas here: http://www.smartquant.com/introduction/OpenQuant.API.zip  .In particular, you might find the design of the `Strategy` class interesting.

Answer (score 4):

I think you're probably looking for design patterns too soon. Suppose someone said "I'm writing an HR system, what design patterns should I use?" or "Accounts Receivable" or "Transport Scheduling".

I think you need to get some basic OO design in place first, then look for points where you need to decrease coupling, introduce points of flexibility and generally refine your design. At this point design patterns start to become important.

"I'm building a house, which construction patterns do I use?"

"Oh you'll need hammers and nails"

Making a choice of patterns too soon tends to lead to ignoring alternatives ...